# Zookeeper and Kafka Bitnami charts failing

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, bitnami

I'm trying to perform the following: https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-scalable-kafka-zookeeper-cluster-kubernetes/

However, after installing the Helm chart for Kafka I get the following:

```
NAME          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
kafka-0       0/1     Running   4 (28s ago)   3m10s
kafka-1       0/1     Running   4 (27s ago)   3m10s
kafka-2       0/1     Running   4 (28s ago)   3m10s
zookeeper-0   1/1     Running   0             13m
zookeeper-1   1/1     Running   0             13m
zookeeper-2   1/1     Running   0             13m
```

The Zookeeper pods run fine, but not the Kafka ones - any idea why? The logs for `kafka-0` end here:

```
andredemoeller:vscan % kubectl logs kafka-0 -c kafka
kafka 16:54:10.96 
kafka 16:54:10.99 Welcome to the Bitnami kafka container
kafka 16:54:11.01 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
kafka 16:54:11.03 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
kafka 16:54:11.05 
kafka 16:54:11.07 INFO  ==> ** Starting Kafka setup **
kafka 16:54:12.35 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
kafka 16:54:12.56 INFO  ==> Initializing Kafka...
kafka 16:54:12.71 INFO  ==> No injected configuration files found, creating default config files
kafka 16:54:23.37 INFO  ==> Configuring Kafka for inter-broker communications with PLAINTEXT authentication.
kafka 16:54:23.46 WARN  ==> Inter-broker communications are configured as PLAINTEXT. This is not safe for production environments.
kafka 16:54:23.49 INFO  ==> Configuring Kafka for client communications with PLAINTEXT authentication.
kafka 16:54:23.61 WARN  ==> Client communications are configured using PLAINTEXT listeners. For safety reasons, do not use this in a production environment.
kafka 16:54:23.90 INFO  ==> ** Kafka setup finished! **

kafka 16:54:24.10 INFO  ==> ** Starting Kafka **
```

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  112s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/kafka-0 to minikube
  Normal   Created    70s (x2 over 111s)   kubelet            Created container kafka
  Normal   Started    70s (x2 over 110s)   kubelet            Started container kafka
  Warning  Unhealthy  31s (x10 over 101s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: dial tcp 10.244.0.219:9092: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  31s (x6 over 91s)    kubelet            Liveness probe failed: dial tcp 10.244.0.219:9092: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Killing    31s (x2 over 71s)    kubelet            Container kafka failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Pulled     30s (x3 over 111s)   kubelet            Container image "docker.io/bitnami/kafka:3.4.0-debian-11-r2" already present on machine
```

It looks like the probes are failing, but unsure how to fix. I've definitely set `--set externalZookeeper.servers=ZOOKEEPER-SERVICE-NAME` correctly.

Comment: Don't use them, then? Look at https://strimzi.io  which can still be installed with Helm

Comment: I have actually seen a very similar issue. For the Kubernetes node where Kafka and ZK are running, what is the host OS and Linux kernel version?